# How would I go on making re sizable and moveable windows modules in a winform app?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, winforms, module

I am currently developing a program where I can view and send data to an Arduino however I am unsure how to create a window Application that I can move the tabe inside it.

This Tab should be scaleable, pinnable, closeable, and can snap into corners or between other modules. Will I have to create this system From scratch or are there already packages out there that do this ?.
**Example of what i try to do**
[image: Example of what i try to do]
all the telemetry data are in single tab, which can be moved or closed. I am trying to build a win form to do that Task

[image: what i have now]
First of all I am trying to make a moveable Tabe , then scale it up with many modules at once. I am having trouble finding information about moveable Tabe in a winform so if you know of any information to help me out please let me know!

Comment: i recommend to don't use the old technolgy winform to do that ... you could use wpf it will be more easy and fun try to fnd [starting tutorials with wpf](https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/about-wpf/what-is-wpf/)

Comment: Take a look at [DockPanel Suite](https://github.com/dockpanelsuite/dockpanelsuite)

Answer (score 0):

In Winforms, maybe you can try `MDI`. The link: [Multiple-Document Interface (MDI) Applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/multiple-document-interface-mdi-applications) is the document to create `MDI Parent&Child` you can refer to.

First, we need to set the "Main Form" as an `MDIContainer`.

```
public MainForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.IsMdiContainer = true;
}
```

Then, set the "Child Form"s' `MdiParent` to the "Main Form".

```
private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Form1
    MdiChildForm newMDIChild = new MdiChildForm();
    newMDIChild.Size = new Size(200, 200);
    newMDIChild.MdiParent = this;
    newMDIChild.Show();
    newMDIChild.Location = new Point(0, 0);
    // Form2
    MdiChildForm2 newMDIChild2 = new MdiChildForm2();
    newMDIChild2.Size = new Size(500, 200);
    newMDIChild2.MdiParent = this;
    newMDIChild2.Show();
    newMDIChild2.Location = new Point(210, 0);
}
```

The test result,
[image]